# Prepending .hbs (handlebars) template extension with a .js or other file name (filename.js.hbs) - Problems?

Tags: javascript, filenames, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

For [Ghost](https://ghost.org/) theme development (with a limited API and no way to create custom filters), is there any problem naming a handlebars template file `filename.js.hbs` ?

Use case: using a handlebars file for theme configuration settings that's 100% javascript but wanting to minimize `<script>` tags (ie: have everything referenced into one `<script>` tag, which means that the contents of the handlebars' config file can't start and end with `<script>` tags, which is ok, **but I want syntax highlighting... this is the main reason**).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Sublime Text, you can select HTML, or JavaScript and it will highlight your syntax. Better, you can install [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) and via Package Control, you can install handlebars related syntax highlighting on Sublime Text.